# Angular WebSocket not attempting to connect

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I have set up a simple WebSocket server in go, and when i try to connect to the server in postman: (ws://localhost:3000/ws), it works without any problems. But when i do the same in angular:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';
import { userdata } from 'src/interfaces/interfaces';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CheckloginService {
  private socket$ = webSocket(`${environment.websocket_url}/ws`);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log("Connect to WebSocket")
  }

  socket = io(`${environment.api_url}/user`) // this remained from an old api, will be removed later
  isLoggedIn() {
    ...
  }

  getUserData() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I checked the network tab, nothing,

Checked the console, nothing

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable are lazy most of the time, you need to subscribe to them to fire the connection.

```
webSocket(`${environment.websocket_url}/ws`).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Its working now, thank you!